# Terminate the Access macro after a specific time

Tags: batch, macros, microsoft-access

I am running several  MS Access macros from a batch file. The macro runs several queries in AccessDB. Things are working fine. But, I want to add a check. If a macro runs longer than a specific time, I would like to skip/ end/ kill that one and proceed to the next command.

I have used the following:

```
taskkill /F /IM msaccess.exe 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "macroname1"
taskkill /F /IM msaccess.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "macroname2"
```

At present, if the first macro runs for a long time, the second one has to wait. I tried TIMEOUT as well. Is there any other option?

Comment: The easiest and best way of handling this would be to include timeouts in your first macro. You can do %time in batch and get a return, but if the batch your running is being held hostage it wouldn't help much.. Unless you put it in a separate batch file altogether. So My vote is to include the timeout in your macros.

Answer (score 0):

You could run your macros using Scheduled Tasks (created with the Task Scheduler included with Windows), with the tasks configured to terminate if the task runs longer than a predefined duration.

This would also allow you to run the macros independently of one another, as each could be queued up as a separate task.